# Reserved word cannot be used in Merge Statement Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, merge, amazon-redshift

I try to run a merge statement on redshift and getting

> ERROR: SQL reparse error.
> Code: 25011 context: syntax error at or near "tag". query: 0 location: omnisql_reparse_sql.cpp:239 process: padbmaster [pid=1073759083]

This is my query:

```
MERGE INTO curated.osipi_target
USING staging.osipi_source 
ON osipi_target."tag" = osipi_source."tag"
AND osipi_target."timestamp" = osipi_source."timestamp"

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
        "tag" = osipi_source."tag",
        "timestamp" = osipi_source."timestamp",
        "value" = osipi_source."value"

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ( 
"tag",
"timestamp",
"value"
)

VALUES (
osipi_source."tag",
osipi_source."timestamp",
osipi_source."value"
)
;
```

I have already used double quotes around all columns and still not working.
can anyone help me to fix this please ?

Comment: It wouldn't really be related to the error message (& I don't have access to a redshift database to try it out), but does redshift allow trailing commas? Those between parenthesis seem odd to me, but surely the one before `WHEN NOT MATCHED` should be a syntax error?

Comment: Hi @Marth , I have edited the statement from the post already 
because Stack Overflow do not allow me to add the full code so, I cut some fields out and forgot to remove the commas behind.

By the way the error is still shown about "tag" error 

Thanks you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the double quotes once you create an alias for a dataset - please try:

```
MERGE INTO curated.osipi_target
USING staging.osipi_source 
ON osipi_target.tag = osipi_source.tag
AND osipi_target.timestamp = osipi_source.timestamp

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
        "tag" = osipi_source.tag,
        "timestamp" = osipi_source.timestamp,
        "value" = osipi_source.value,

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ( 
"tag",
"timestamp",
"value",
)

VALUES (
osipi_source.tag,
osipi_source.timestamp,
osipi_source.value,
);
```

Comment: Hi d1sh4, thank you for the suggestion but I have tried your code and still getting another error `ERROR: syntax error at or near "tag" Position: 115 [ErrorId: 1-65002ba7-2f3adb34721e33fa6d81b6af]`

Comment: I've corrected it once again - could you try now?

Comment: Hi d1sh4, I've tried your code again and still getting the same error as above. Using double quote or not using double quote cause the same error